# Symfony 2 Config File Types

Tags: configuration, symfony

I generated a bundle and set it to use annotations for config files. But I find that in `Resources/config/services.xml`, its still XML? Perhaps it because I cant configure services using annotations? If so how can I make it use yml if thats the case? I could just add a YML file but I dont suppose it will be detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that you can't define a service using Annotations is correct. You need to have either a `services.xml` or `services.yml` under `Resources/config` for the bundle.

Check out the answers to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317817/move-symfony2-service-config-to-bundle)**, it covers how to define a service using both `xml`, `yml` and through a `config.yml` import.

I've also written an answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021730/symfony2-doctrine-having-to-put-business-logic-in-my-controller-and-duplicatin/8023773#8023773)** on the basics of defining a service.

Comment: So I need to create an Extension Class just to let symfony know a service.yml is there? I can't just put the config in `app/config/config.yml` like shown in the docs?

Comment: You can just put the whole service definition into `app/config/config.yml` or you can import a `services.yml` file from your bundle into the main `config.yml`. OR What the `Extension` class does is stop you from having to do the import `services.yml` into `config.yml` manually, instead symfony will be able to autoload it (it's good if your bundle is standalone and you don't want people to have to activate your bundle's services in any way).